# API call to reload grid not working

Tags: jqgrid

This question might be a repeat question, but I am adding it as a new question because all of the answers mentioned in similar questions are not working for me.

```
jqGridObj.setGridParam({ datatype: "json"}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

At this line of execution, I observe the browser console and it does make a new json call properly and the response of this fresh call also does have the latest data from the server. However, some how the new records are not populated in the grid. I need to manually refresh the page to see the new records.

Comment: Are you needing to change the datatype, if not does a call  to jqGridObj.trigger("reloadGrid"); without the datatype change work fine?

Comment: Right, I think we need a bit more information to figure out what is going on here. Also, what datatype are you using before you set it to JSON? Why do you need to change it?

Answer (score 0):

I use try this:

```
$("#NAME_GRID").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

See the [link](http://pastebin.com/tDCMgaNb) with containg a example a code the jqgrid with call the reload.

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to what the problem is with the OP's code, and how this resolves the problem?

Comment: The code loads the grid according to call the URL. like this http://pastebin.com/tDCMgaNb and that event `ReloadGrid()` you call by the button for eg.

Comment: 1. Answers should be self-contained rather than relying on links that might not always be available. 2. Edit your answer rather than responding in comments. (FYI, I encountered this as a Low Quality Posts review. I voted not to delete, but I do think the answer needs some embellishment. I'm not asking you to explain this to me personally, I'm suggesting that you improve the quality of the answer.)